# How to fix esi:remove tag og litespeed not displaying broken in frontend of my eshop

Tags: caching, plesk, cs-cart, litespeed

I am very new to litespeed. I have installed the addon in cs-cart platform, following the instructions here:

https://github.com/litespeedtech/lscache-cscart

After installing and activating the addon, which does not have any configs, I saw some `esi:remove` tags in the frontend of my eshop. I have already append (**at the end**) of my htaccess file the recommended code below:

```
# Full-page cache add-on
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
    RewriteEngine on
    CacheLookup on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !(esi\.php|api\.php|admin\.php|cart/|checkout/|checkout\-customer\-info/|checkout\-summary/|orders/|compare/|wishlist/)
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !dispatch=(checkout\..+|orders\..+|wishlist\..+|product_features\.add_product|product_features\.clear_list|product_features\.delete_product|product_features\.delete_feature|product_features\.compare)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}   !disable_cache=Y
    RewriteRule .* - [E=cache-control:max-age=900,E=esi_on:1]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !esi\.php
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}   sid_customer_
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_X_HAS_SESSION:true,E=cache-control:vary=hassession,E=esi_on:1]
</IfModule>
```

I noticed that the `esi:remove` tag is appearing wherever there is an input type hidden field, but tag is broken..

I have attached some images, to understand better (console log):

[image]

Frontend  eshop:

[image]

Should I make configurations on my server? Should I restart any services, or do something else?
Anyone could help, I would be appreciated

Server info:
Plesk Obsidian v18.0.59_build1800240229.10 os_Debian 10.0

Debian 10.13

PHP version: 7.4

Manage LiteSpeed Web Server:

Current version 6.2.1 (build 1) - Latest Build: 2 -- I guess there is an update